# Deploying WebApplication as a WAR file on Weblogic using SFTP Adapter

Tags: spring, web-applications, sftp, weblogic-10.x

I have configured SFTP Adapter configurations in Spring Aplication file and i have one JAR which is including in that war file & i have rsa file on resource location of that Jar file but when i try to deploy it on Weblogic 10.3.6.0 it does not find rsa file and gives the following error:

POM.XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abc.tsi</groupId>
    <artifactId>tsi-ibs2bank</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Project</name>

    <modules>
        <module>tsi-a-core</module>
        <module>tsi-b-services</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>    
    <properties>
        <cxf.version>3.0.1</cxf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Stacktrace:

```
 synchronizing remote to local directory
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:209)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:167)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:144)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:192)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:314)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:440)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:139)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain pooled item
        at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:177)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory.getSession(CachingSessionFactory.java:118)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:310)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:167)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:168)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
        at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:354)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:76)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:73)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:187)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:167)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/classpath*:WEB-INF/id_rsa] cannot be resolved to absolute file path - web application archive not expanded?
        at org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.getRealPath(WebUtils.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getFile(ServletContextResource.java:176)
        at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.initJschSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:370)
```

Application.xml

```
    <bean id="defaultSftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${sftp.host}" />
    <property name="user" value="${sftp.username}" />
<!--<property name="password" value="${sftp.password}"/> -->
    <property name="port" value="${sftp.serverPort}" />

    <property name="privateKey" value="${sftp.private.keyfile}" />
    <property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="${sftp.passphrase}" />

    </bean>

<bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="defaultSftpSessionFactory" />

</bean>
```

Comment: What is `sftp.private.keyfile` set to when looking for the `id_rsa` file? Have you tried making it `/WEB-INF/id_rsa` with the slash on the front?

Comment: It didnot worked with this location as well.
sftp.private.keyfile=classpath*:/WEB-INF/id_rsa
sftp.private.keyfile is defined in a properties file which is in that JAR.